# IIS - how to provide "Quality of Service" on different parts of my site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

My website has a requirement for large downloads (50GB files). I do not want any large downloads/uploads to affect the performance of other pages loading. Is there a way to limit bandwidth to certain parts of my site so that all combined users will never be able to download more than X-Mb a second? I must use a single IP to reach my site.

I have tried:

- Splitting the site into sub domains and implementing limits of bandwidth. This works fine with HTTP but not HTTPS, which seems to ignore it.
- Applied QoS as a group policy. This works for the whole server but
  does not seem to work for individual pages.
- Apply QoS (on a Cisco router), based on URL, but this only works with the new XE IOS versions.

Comment: When you say "HTTPS seems to ignore it," what does "it" refer to? Possibly your TLS bindings aren't set up properly. Do you mean that HTTPS traffic is ignoring your subdomains, or ignoring your subdomains?

Comment: Any HTTPS traffic completely ignores any bandwidth limits i set under IIS Limits. I set a limit of 1Mb and the file transfers at 10Mb (only with HTTPS addresses).

Comment: It sounds like this may not be your problem, but I've seen SSL bindings route traffic in unexpected ways, so possibly the HTTPS is hitting a different site than you assume

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I checked and its the right binding.